# How to import/reference multiple pytest fixtures without wildcard import?

Tags: pytest

Currently I use the following setup to import pytest fixtures from a file called `fixtures.py` and run tests with them:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.core import mail
from main.tests.fixtures import user_a, group_dropoff_for_qc

def test_should_check_password(db, user_a: User) -> None:
    user_a.set_password("secret")
    assert user_a.check_password("secret") is True

# more tests here
```

As I write more tests and use more fixtures, that import list from `main.tests.fixtures` grows really long. Is there some built-in pytest way around this? This seems like such a common operation that there should be a more streamlined approach.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on my own, so here is the solution in case this helps anyone else.

Solution source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pytest/pytest_conftest_py.htm

If you rename an exterior file that contains fixtures to `conftest.py`, you can reference the fixtures in that file without needing to explicitly import them.  So in my case above, I just had to rename my `fixtures.py` to `conftest.py`, which allowed me to run the tests as expected, without the import statement:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.core import mail

def test_should_check_password(db, user_a: User) -> None:
    user_a.set_password("secret")
    assert user_a.check_password("secret") is True

# more code here
```